# How to submit multipart/form-data with File and Text Fields using Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, multipartform-data

This registration form contains a file upload and textfields. Using Struts2 how do we submit the form parameters and also upload the file?

1. `register.jsp`:

```jsp
<s:form action = "Register" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="uname" label = "User Name"/>  
    <s:password name ="password" label = "Password"/>
    <s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40" />
    <s:submit/> 
</s:form>
```

2. `RegisterAction`:

```java
package user.action;

import java.io.File;

public class RegisterAction 
{
    private String uname,password;
    private File fileUpload;
    private String fileUploadContentType;
    private String fileUploadFileName;

    //getter setters

    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

3. `struts.xml`:

```xml
</action>
<action name="Register" class="user.action.RegisterAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
        <param name="maximumSize">10240</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success">registered.jsp</result>
</action>
```

4. `registered.jsp`:

```jsp
User Name    : <s:property value="uname"/>
File Name    : <s:property value="fileUploadFileName"/> 
Content Type : <s:property value="fileUploadContentType"/> 
File         : <s:property value="fileUpload"/>
```

User Name `<s:property value="uname"/>`  is not giving any output in
`registered.jsp`.  Should we use Apache file upload to parse the request to get the textfields value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. The Apache file upload is part of Struts2. The `fileUpload` interceptor is already included to the `defaultStack`, so you don't need to reference it in the action configuration. If you want to override parameters of this interceptor then

```xml
<action name="Register" class="user.action.RegisterAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
        <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">10240</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success">registered.jsp</result>
</action>
```

> As long as the required libraries are added to your project you will be able to take advantage of of the Struts 2 fileUpload capability.

Answer (score 0):

check you setter methods local variable and in registered.jsp try this
change

```
User Name <s:property value="uname"/>
```

with

```
<s:label name="xyz" value="%{uname}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friends for looking into the problem.
I have got the answer. Actually I had done a mistake while adding the interceptor.
I had missed

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
```

so my new action after change should be

```
  <action name="Register" class="user.action.RegisterAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
            <param name="maximumSize">10240</param>
        </interceptor-ref> 
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">registered.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Mr Roman is correct that we should add the file upload interceptor only if we need to override. If we don't still it will upload.